# Add reference to member object to array of pointers

Tags: c++

I have a class with some private members containing objects and a dynamic array of pointers which i want to fill with pointers to some of those member object.

```
class NextionTest : public NextionDisplay {
private:
  NexText           lblText =   NexText(0,  1, "t0");
  NexButton       btnPage1  =   NexButton(  0,  2,  "b0");
  NexButton       btnPage0  =   NexButton(  1,  1,  "b0");

  NexTouch *nex_listen_list = [    
                &lblText,
                &btnPage0,  
                &btnPage1,
                NULL 
  ];
 /* rest of class not shown */
};
```

The above code result in this error:

> capture of non-variable 'NextionTest::lblText' 
>        &lblText,

I tried to move the initialization of the nex_listen_list to a init method but this gives the same result.
I have no idea what a capture is.. but seems i'm doing something wrong.
How to solve this?

Comment: my innocent guess (not really familiar with c++11 and beyond) is that `[]` looks like you wanted to declare a lambda. e.g. `[x]` as part of a lambda means: capture x by value. Try `{}` instead, or `{{}}` or whatever is correct ;) I am really no expert on initializer list

Comment: Your compiler things you are declaring a lambda function. What is the definition of NexTouch? And if it was, say an array of pointers of, toy should use aggregate initialization: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: Instead of guessing about syntax I suggest picking up a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks for your very constructive comment

Comment: `nex_listen_list` is not a dynamic array, you probably want a `std::vector<NexTouch*>`. The way this is set up though, if your object is moved or copied you will be left with a bunch of references, either dangling or into another object.

Comment: Bascy, refrain from moving the bar on an answered question by changing the question to match the answer's suggestion. Instead ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a `std::vector`, which is dynamic and knows its size.

```
class NextionTest : public NextionDisplay {
private:
  NexText           lblText =   NexText(0,  1, "t0");
  NexButton       btnPage1  =   NexButton(  0,  2,  "b0");
  NexButton       btnPage0  =   NexButton(  1,  1,  "b0");

  std::vector<NexTouch*> nex_listen_list = {    
                &lblText,
                &btnPage0,  
                &btnPage1};
 /* rest of class not shown */
};
```

However this class will behave poorly if copied or moved.  If I did

```
NextionTest n1;
auto n2 = n1;
```

`n2.nex_listen_list` will have pointers into the data members of `n1`, so you should delete the copy and move operations

```
class NextionTest : public NextionDisplay {
    NextionTest(const NextionTest&) = delete;
    NextionTest& operator=(const NextionTest&) = delete
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your array this way:

```
NexTouch* nex_listen_list[4] = {
    &lblText,
    &btnPage0,
    &btnPage1,
    nullptr
};
```

However, this defines a fixed size array, and it seems from seeing the "null-termination" that your intent is to have a dynamic array that grows/shrinks and is always terminated by `nullptr` similarly to strings. In this case, it is better to use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<NexTouch*> nex_listen_list = {
    &lblText,
    &btnPage0,
    &btnPage1,
    nullptr
};
```

The nullptr-termination is usually not needed, but depends on what you want to do with the array. If you will send it to some API that takes an old-style array you can use `nex_listen_list.data()` to retrieve the embedded C-style array.